# Arduino - Uploading sketch in vs code failed, But Arduino IDE OK

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

```
#include <DS3231.h>
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
  Serial.println("Setup...");
}

void loop()
{
   Serial.println("Loop...");
  // // Send time
  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());
  delay(2000);
}
```

This is simple code. Uploading this skecth in Arduino IDE works well, I can see the serial logs

```
Setup...
Loop...
12:18:01
Loop...
12:18:03
Loop...
12:18:05
```

With No problem.
But when I upload this code in `VS Code`, It wouldn't work.

The output below

```
[Starting] Uploading sketch 'smartfarm.ino'
Please see the build logs in output path: c:\Projects\ArduinoOutput
설정파일 로딩... // loading configuration...
패키지 초기화... // initializing packages...
보드 준비...     // ready to board...
확인...          // ok...
C:\Users\appton-2\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:77:7: warning: type 'struct DS3231' violates the C++ One Definition Rule [-Wodr]
class DS3231
       ^
C:\Users\appton-2\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231\DS3231.h:62:7: note: a different type is defined in another translation unit
^
C:\Users\appton-2\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:100:11: note: the first difference of corresponding definitions is field '_scl_pin'
uint8_t _scl_pin;
           ^
C:\Users\appton-2\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231\DS3231.h:69:13: note: a field with different name is defined in another translation unit
uint8_t  date;
             ^
C:\Users\appton-2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccp574Yq.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `global constructors keyed to 65535_0_smartfarm.ino.cpp.o.1845':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x60): undefined reference to `DS3231::DS3231(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
C:\Users\appton-2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccp574Yq.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `setup':
c:\Projects\smartfarm/smartfarm.ino:9: undefined reference to `DS3231::begin()'
C:\Users\appton-2\AppData\Local\Temp\ccp574Yq.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `loop':
c:\Projects\smartfarm/smartfarm.ino:16: undefined reference to `DS3231::getTimeStr(unsigned char)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
IntelliSense configuration already up to date. To manually rebuild your IntelliSense configuration run "Ctrl+Alt+I"
[Error] Uploading sketch 'smartfarm.ino': Exit with code=1
```

Do you know the reason? Am I missing something? I changed DS3231 lib to another lib.

Comment: "I changed DS3231 lib to another lib." what does this mean?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I deleted DS3231 lib and download another library and put it in same location.

Comment: Please show what library you put in its place. If DS3231.h that you're using isn't the same as the one I'm looking at, then we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works well. The reason was I guess "Output Path" in vs code arduino. vs code ask me to input outputPath for fast building before. Perhaps the previous library remained here even if I changed to new one. I removed all files in outputPath now it works fine :) –